# How to access (check or uncheck) radio(option) button in active sheet by c# vsto addin

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I want to check or uncheck radio button in excel sheet from c#, created by approach of developer-> insert -> radio button on some condition. how can I get radio button object from active sheet. 
[image]
I think it can be accessed by control name such as option button1 , option button 2. but I don't know how to access controls from sheet object.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get Excel option button with index as follow

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OptionButton opt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.OptionButton)currentSheet.OptionButtons(1);
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me, I want to know how to set checked or unchecked state to that option button, I can't find method to set in this object.

Comment: you can set value field to true or false `opt.Value=true // for checked`

Comment: Thanks alot that's what I want exactly

Comment: Ha! OptionButtons is a dynamic type collection.  You don't know it's there if you don't know how to look for it.  Thank you!! This helped me out.